# Basic Question: Possible Jordan Canonical forms of a given $5 \times 5$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this exercise question from the book "A second course in linear algebra" and I am struggling to get a sense of this. This is probably embarrassingly simple and I do apologize in advance.

If $A \in M_5$, $(A−2I)^3 = 0$, and $(A−2I)^2 \neq 0$, what are the possible Jordan canonical forms for $A$?

Comment: Use [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174116/jordan-canonical-form-of-a-5-times5-matrix?rq=1), but with  $(A-2I)^3=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**: [Assuming that we're working over $\Bbb C$ (or some other algebraically closed field).]

1. Do you see that all the eigenvalues of $A$ must be $2$? (Why? Suppose $\lambda \neq 2$ is an eigenvalue and $v \neq 0$ is a corresponding eigenvector, what happens when you compute $(A - 2 I)v$? $(A - 2I)^2v$?...)
2. Suppose that all the Jordan blocks are of size at most $2$. What happens to $(A - 2I)^2$ then? Conclude that there is at least one Jordan block of size at least $3$.
3. What happens if there's a Jordan block of size at least $4$? Compute $(A - 2I)^3$ and conclude that that's not possible.
4. Conclude that there is one Jordan block of size $3$. What choices are left for the other block(s)? Show that both are possible.

---

In the above, you may assume that $A$ itself is in its Jordan form. (Why?)

It may be useful to recall how block matrices are multiplied.